# most recent result before a date given a condition SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some data in SQlite with columns : ID | Rating | date

I want to return only the IDs whose most recent rating before a certain date is greater than 7

I have been trying for an hour now, but can't figure it out. Can anyone please help? Is it even possible?

Edit :Here is the table, ID's are not unique, as one ID has ratings at different dates.

```
CREATE TABLE subset_all(
  "ID" TEXT,
  "RatingDate" TEXT,
  "Rating" TEXT,
  "SegType" TEXT,
);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you storing dates in one of the formats supported by [sqlite date and time functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), all of which have the added bonus of being able to be meaningfully compared to see which is greater or less than another?

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Actual table definition, sample data (As `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements!), and expected results for that data are things that are important to include.

Comment: @Shawn I added the table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach using the window functions in modern versions of sqlite (3.25 or newer):

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT id, rating, date
           , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
      FROM ratings
      WHERE date < :yourdate)
WHERE rating > 7 AND rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Without window functions, first group by id to get the most recent date of rating (before a certain date) and then join to the table:

```
select s.*
from subset_all s inner join (
  select id, max(date) maxdate 
  from subset_all
  where date < ?
  group by id
) g on g.id = s.id and g.maxdate = s.date
where s.rating > 7
```

Replace `?` with date limit you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most recent rating using a correlated subquery.  Then filter:

```
select t.*
from subset_all t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from subset_all t2
                where t2.id = t.id and
                      t2.date <= ?  -- your cutoff date
               ) and
      t.rating > 7
```

Comment: All the data is in one table, will it work if t2 = t1?

Comment: @Frank . . . Of course.  The query assumes there is only one table.